# javascript keyword finder loop

Tags: javascript

This program is suppose to find keyword & open the link only 1 time, but the loop keeps opening infinity links. please help!

```
var keywordName = "miller macc";
var split = keywordName.split(" ");
var tFunction = "twitterScan()";
var tweet = new Array();
var tweetName = new Array();

function twitterScan()
{
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) 
{
    tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;


if (tweet[0].match(split[i]) == split[i])
{document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();}

else {location.reload(true);}
}   
}
setTimeout(tFunction, 200);
```

Comment: n_n always indent your code, it will help you, it will help us.. welcome to the world of coding

Comment: Issue is probably here `tweet[0].match(split[i]) == split[i]` as `match` returns an array or `null`.

Comment: So the loop only runs once if I am only searching 1 keywordName..otherwise, searching multiple words makes it into a infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You were not stopping the timer. So it was performing the same action for infinite interval. Try this:

```
var keywordName = "miller macc";
var split = keywordName.split(" ");
var tFunction = "twitterScan()";
var tweet = new Array();
var tweetName = new Array();

var t;

function twitterScan() {
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
        tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;

        var tweetMatch = tweet[0].match(split[i]);
        if (tweetMatch != null && tweetMatch == split[i]) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();  
        } else {
            location.reload(true);
        }
            clearTimeout(t);
    }
}
t = setTimeout(tFunction, 200);
```

Comment: So the loop only runs once if I am only searching 1 keywordName..otherwise, searching multiple words makes it into a infinite loop

Comment: it will run as many times as there are keywords. so for "miller macc" it should run 2 times. is this what is happening ?

Comment: No, it opens an infinite number of new tabs

Comment: i have updated the code and moved clearTimeout(t); outside if-else. Try it now

Comment: still no luck..same problem.